# Forcing compatibility of inherited types (Python)

Tags: python, inheritance

Assume someone gave you an existing pair of classes that work together:

```
class non_unique_collection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_items = []
    def add_new_item(self, item):
        self.all_items.append(item)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.all_items)
    ## ...
    ## there are several other useful functions here
    ## ...
    def overlap(self, n_u_tuple):
        # do some things here
        pass

class non_unique_ranked_collection:
    def __init__(self, some_scores_and_items):
        self.ranked_items = sorted(some_scores_and_items)
```

I want to use many functions of that class (e.g. `__len__`), but I want to change something very basic:

```
class unique_collection(non_unique_collection):
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_items = set([])
    def add_new_item(self, item):
        self.all_items.add(item)
```

I also want to use my derived `unique_collection` class with another new class `unique_ranked_collection`:

```
class unique_ranked_collection(non_unique_ranked_collection):
    def __init__(self, some_scores_and_items):
        # average scores for duplicate items
        items_to_scores = {}
        for score, item in some_scores_and_items:
            if item in items_to_scores:
                items_to_scores[item].append(score)
            else:
                items_to_scores[item] = [ score ]
        average_scores_and_unique_items = dict( [ (sum(items_to_scores[item])/float(len(items_to_scores[item])), item) for item in items_to_scores ] )
        self.ranked_items = sorted(average_scores_and_unique_items)
```

Here is my question:

What is the *best* way to make it so that the `overlap` function can be used with a `non_unique_collection` and a `non_unique_ranked_collection` or with a `unique_collection` and a `unique_ranked_collection` (but *not* between a `unique...` and `non_unique...` types)? I started to put in some assert statements using `isinstance`, but it started to look messy, and I wanted to ask for advice.

The best thing I could think of was to have two base classes that both the `unique...` and `non_unique...` types inherit from. What do you think about that?

Thanks a lot.

PS-- I know this specific problem that the code is written for is pretty uninteresting, but it's just an illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think twice if you really want to enforce this.  Strict type checking is not recommended for Python since it prevents "duck typing".

Furthermore, inheritance in object-oriented programming models an *is-a*  relationship.  Since `unique_ranked_collection` inherits from `non_unique_ranked_collection`, an instance of the former class *is* a kind of the latter class:

```
>>> obj = unique_ranked_collection()
>>> isinstance(obj, non_unique_ranked_collection)
True
```

Consequently, `non_unique_collection.overlap()` *should* accept a `unique_ranked_collection`.

If you must enforce that `unique_collection.overlap()` only accepts a `unique_ranked_collection`, just override the method:

```
class unique_collection(non_unique_collection):

    # ...

    def overlap(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, unique_ranked_collection):
            raise TypeError('expected an unique_ranked_collection')
        return super(unique_collection, self).overlap(other)
```

Comment: This doesn't over if both `self` and `other` are `unique_collection`s, and it requires multiple `overlap`s be defined.

Comment: +1 And marked as the answer-- it is not the Python way to do this! I want to code in C++. : )

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly mention which "types" you want to allow calls to `overlap` on, by tagging the classes, and making `overlap` an external function instead of a method on all classes.

This isn't very pythonic, I think, because it tries to force types on the classes, but they are weak types, think of them as "overlap buckets", but it depends on your actual use case.

Another problem is that in your examples, `unique_collection` **is a** `non_unique_collection` (inherits from it) and similarly `unique_ranked_collection` **is a** `non_unique_ranked_collection`, which means you'll need a complicated matrix of classes to sort this out, or use something like the example below:

```
class non_unique_collection:
    type = 'N'

class non_unique_ranked_collection:
    type = 'N'

class unique_collection(non_unique_collection):
    type = 'U'

class unique_ranked_collection(non_unique_ranked_collection):
    type = 'U'

def overlap(collection1, collection2):
    if collection1.type != collection2.type:
        raise TypeError
    return True
```

Comment: `<>` is deprecated, don't use it. I agree this is not a very Pythonic solution, but it does work the same way as mine, and you could still use a base class if you wanted `overlap` to be an instance method.

Comment: Yeah, `<>` has been removed in Python 3, and is "considered obsolescent" in Python 2.7, but I like how it looks.  Probably a bad idea to use it on StackOverflow. Using inheritance here is tricky, given that `unique_collection` IS A `non_unique_collection` according to the original question.

Comment: I don't see what's tricky -- `type = 'N'` would just be overridden by the `unique` classes, and `overlap` would still lookup the `type`, it would just get `collection1` implicitly as `self`.

Comment: Tricky, as in harder to read, figure out the MRO, and what the `type` attribute is.  "Explicit is better than implicit." But like I said, it depends on how/where this is being used.

Comment: There is nothing implicit about inheritance, but I guess I'd believe harder to read (though he mentioned this was just a toy example, in a real situation attributes are much more easily lost in the noise than base classes). Your version fails the principal of least astonishment, in that `type(collection) is not collection.type`. Renaming it to `is_unique` or something works around that, however.

Comment: yes, I mentioned the "overlap bucket" idea in the explanation, not sure if that is the best term for it though.

Comment: I'm not convinced that free functions are unpythonic.  eg: `len()`, `iter()`, `sorted()`.  What's the rationale for that opinion?

Comment: Free functions are great for multi-dispatch, like in this example.  I meant that the whole "type"/"overlap bucket" attribute seemed unpythonic (not very "ducky").